# Controlling itunes through Java cross platform

Tags: java, cross-platform, itunes

My brief requires me to control itunes through a Java Program and must work on either OS X or Windows.

From my research it seems most people's Windows Control uses the Itunes/COM SDK over a COM bridge, and Mac control uses Applescript.

Thing is I can't seem to find a way to develop this to be truely cross platform, because the libraries I need for OSX seems to be inbuilt and non-accessible from windows.

So I was wondering if anyone had a solution, or another cross platform way to control iTunes from either operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need some commands like Play, pause, stop, next etc. you could try just to simulate a global keyPress event and sent the right KeyCode (for the multimedia Keys). In Java you can use JNI to call a simple C program which will simulates a Keypress for you...or you look at the Robot class in Java.

In windows the function is called: keybd_event(keycode,0,0,0);

The only problem is that other programs (if started) would probably also react to the multimedia keypresses.